# Test kafka listener inside a module in Spring Boot

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out how to make a test to pass inside a module in a Spring Boot app written in Kotlin.

The following class and test are located in the "root" module of the application and it's working perfect.

demo-testconstainers->src->main->kotlin->com.example.demotestcontainers

```
package com.example.demotestcontainers.kafka

import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class KafkaListener(private val useCase: UseCase) {

    @KafkaListener(topics = ["\${consumer.topic.name}"], groupId = "demo")
    fun listener(event: String){
        println("message received")
        println(event)
        useCase.foo()
    }
}
```

And the test is the following:

```
package com.example.demotestcontainers.kafka

import com.example.demotestcontainers.database.MongoDB
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito.timeout
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpyBean
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource
import org.testcontainers.containers.KafkaContainer
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName
import org.mockito.Mockito.verify
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate

@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(properties = ["spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest"])
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=[MongoAutoConfiguration::class])
class KafkaListenerTest {
    companion object {
        @Container
        private val kafkaContainer = KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.3"))

        @JvmStatic
        @DynamicPropertySource
        fun overrideProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", kafkaContainer::getBootstrapServers);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, Any>

    @SpyBean
    @MockBean
    private lateinit var useCase: UseCase

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var mongoDB: MongoDB

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var mongoTemplate: MongoTemplate

    @Test
    fun `invoke the use case`() {
        println("listening in port: ${kafkaContainer.bootstrapServers}")
        kafkaTemplate.send("test-topic", "message")

        verify(useCase, timeout(5000).times(1)).foo()
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to do something similar but inside a different module like the following:

demo-testconstainers->module->src->main->kotlin->com.example.demotestcontainers.module

The listener never receives the message sent during the test so the test is failing. I tried adding a test configuration class in the folder

demo-testconstainers->module->src->test->kotlin->com.example.demotestcontainers.module

but is not working

```
package com.example.demotestcontainers.module

import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration

@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class ModuleTestConfiguration() {}
```

I think I'm missing something critical related to the framework but I'm quite new with Spring Boot.

Comment: Packages (not modules) shouldn't matter, IMO. But what dependency versions are you using? I will point out that you can just use mocks for this test since you're not really doing anything that requires the value of the consumed event

Comment: By the way, you'll introduce a race condition in your tests by using the same group.id for each invocation

Comment: oneCriketeer 2.7.15 for spring boot. I added the @SpringBootApplication annotation to the test and now it's working but I'm not sure if it's the right thing to do here.

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use newer version of Spring 3? And that annotation is fine; that's what will setup your Component annotation